# is it possible to use VS Profiler (Perfomance Wizard) on machine without VS installed?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have performance issue that can not be reproduced on my development machine.

Issue only reproduce on "deployment" machine so I have to run profiler right there (normally I use development machine for such type of work).

Can I do that remotely? For example can I use Visual Studio UI from my development machine to run profiler via network on deployment machine?

Probably I can install only "profiler" part (without VS) to deployment machine and run it from command-line via RDP?

What options do I have? Of course I can just install VS on deployment machine but I want to install as less things as possible as this machine is used for business and VS is not required there.

**upd** just googled Standalone Profiler http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23205 Probably this is what I need...